# Laptop won't charge - burnt DC Jack

Tags: laptop, motherboard, repair, charging, soldering

I bought the MSI GS63VR 6RF 3 years ago or so and all of a sudden the laptop begin to stop charging unless I lifted the charger cable, directly at the port, in an upwards direction.

I thought the lead was going but on reflection it may have been the port loosening.

I use this laptop for work and with COVID-19 couldn't get it fixed.

Fast-forward a few more days and all of a sudden I heard a crackling coming from the port and then a plume of smoke just flew out and that was it - no more charging.

So it won't charge now at all. I have removed the charger and not put it in since. The laptop worked fine until it died when the battery ran out.

I have read online about this fault and found the charger port replacement.

I only have a soldering iron and solder, so I likely won't do the repair myself and will bring it to a shop. Though if it seems easy enough and something I could do with limited equipment I would give it a go.

My main question here is that I have opened the unit up and took a look on the motherboard base and see some burnt area near the power jack.

I haven't yet taken it apart fully to look at the top side and see the damage. But can do.

Does anyone know if simply repairing the charger port would solve the issue?

Also does anyone know exactly what that burnt area is?

Dc port:

[image]

I don't have the money quoted by MSI for the repairs unfortunately and need the laptop for work.

Comment: If you have a shop near you, that is your best hope. It could be just the power input jack. Without the correct or very close fit, it may be hard to repair. If the bent plug caused a short to the power line inside, it could have done more damage than just the power jack.

Comment: Be optimistic, because the trace that's burnt is close to the jack, so likely the jack can be fixed or replaced and the connection bridged with a short piece of wire. If the repair estimate is more than the depreciated value of the laptop, you might try it repairing it yourself with a *fine tip* iron, magnifier and a service manual. The video at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rtoElBsA9UU shows how to access the jack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Does anyone know if simply repairing the charger port would solve the issue?**

I suspect you could clean up and re-solder the existing connection. This has a reasonable chance of restoring normal operation

> **Also does anyone know exactly what that burnt area is?**

It looks like there was a poor solder connection that consequently had a higher than normal resistance and overheated. The solder joint was probably weak to begin with and may have fractured due to mechanical movement. It looks like it got quite hot but the PCB traces may still be OK.

Connectors like this get a lot of mechanical strain from repeated plugging and unplugging so mechanical attachment to the motherboard is an important design and manufacturing issue. Hence the two large solder-lugs near the outside edge  which mechanically secure the connector.